# Error while Import package into Teams app studio

Tags: microsoft-teams

When we try to import package its showing the validation error while importing, but no errors when building the packages  [Import package error by validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm95N.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the app studio. As a work around please try uploading your app using below options.

1. Developer portal (preview) in app studio
2. Upload a custom app from apps.

We have raised a bug and the concerned team is looking into it.

The same issue is raised on [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/3788) and you can track it for future updates